# Postman to prometheus and carriage "\r"?. text format parsing error in line 1: expected float as value, got "1\r"

Tags: unix, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

Just trying to add new metric to Prometheus through the Postman, but getting

> text format parsing error in line 1: expected float as value, got
> "1\r"

Metric just like

```
"test_metric 1
"
```

(without quotes)

Why it happens and how can i remove it from postman's request?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is in difference between [\r and \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r), so i found workaround using **Pre-request script**, so just open this tab in Postman and add :

```
pm.request.body.update(pm.request.body.raw.replace(/\r/g, ''))
```

It will remove all `\r` from you body. And don't forget to leave new line in body as prometheus need it for metric

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Postman pre-request script cannot change `pm.request.body`. In stead you can specify a *{{body}}* variable, and set it using the pre-request script.

> var body = `your body text`.replace(/\r/g, '');
>
> pm.variables.set('body', body);

See: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9020